# How to update Postgresql view?

Tags: postgresql

I created a View in postgresql database as follows(without where)-

```
CREATE
  VIEW visits_completed_per_day_view as select
    cast(vt.time_started_visit as date) as date
    , count(*)
  FROM
    visit v
    JOIN visit_time vt ON
      vt.visit_code = v.visit_code
  WHERE
    vt.time_started_visit > '2017-09-01'
    and v.campaign_id is null
    AND v.status in ('COMPLETED','FULLY_PAID','REFUNDED')
  GROUP BY date
  ORDER BY date
```

Now I want to change the condition for creation of view as (without vt.time_started_visit > '2017-09-01'
        and v.campaign_id is null) -

```
create
  VIEW visits_completed_per_day_view as select
    cast(vt.time_started_visit as date) as date
    , count(*)
  FROM
    visit v
    JOIN visit_time vt ON
      vt.visit_code = v.visit_code
  WHERE
    v.status in ('COMPLETED', 'FULLY_PAID', 'REFUNDED')
  GROUP BY date
  ORDER BY date
```

How do I do that? I used following query but it's not updating.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW visits_completed_per_day_view as select cast(vt.time_started_visit as date) as Date, count(*)

FROM visit v

JOIN visit_time vt on vt.visit_code = v.visit_code

WHERE 

v.status in ('COMPLETED','FULLY_PAID','REFUNDED')

GROUP BY Date
ORDER BY Date
```

Comment: `ORDER BY date` Dont use reserved words as identifiers.They'll bite back... (Also:dont trust on the case of identifiers ...)

Comment: what makes you think the vie is not changed?.. please elaborate the post